# Keeping `text` and `tikzpicture` on same level in `minipage`

Tags: enumerate, minipage

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning}
\def\baselinestretch{2.0}
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm} 
\setlength{\textheight}{21cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.15cm}


\begin{document}
   If we want to display a real number in decimal point representation (non-scientific format), the character
sequence becomes \%w.pf. The character sequence \%w.pf indicates that the associated data item should be
output as a floating-point number, in non-scientific format, which occupies a field of at least w characters,
and has n figures after the decimal point.\vspace{0.5cm}\\
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.35\textwidth}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item printf(”\%f”,12. 3456);\;$\to$
        \item printf(”\%7.4f”,12. 3456);\;$\to$
        \item printf(”\%7.2f”,12. 3456);\;$\to$
        \item printf(”\%-7.2f”,12. 3456);\;$\to$
        \item printf(”\%8.4f”,-12. 3456);\;$\to$
        \item printf(”\%7.4f”,-12. 3456);\;$\to$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.35\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm](1){1};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 1](2){2};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 2](.){.};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = .](3){3};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 3](4){4};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 4](5){5};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 5](6){6};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 6](0){0};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 0]{0};
    \end{tikzpicture}\vspace{0.2cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm](1){1};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 1](2){2};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 2](.){.};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = .](3){3};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 3](4){4};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 4](5){5};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 5](6){6};
    \end{tikzpicture}\vspace{0.2cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 6](0){};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 0](0'){};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 0'](1){1};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 1](2){2};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 2](.){.};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = .](3){3};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 3](5){5};
    \end{tikzpicture}\vspace{0.2cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm](1){1};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 1](2){2};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 2](.){.};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = .](3){3};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 3](5){5};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 5](0){};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 0]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}\vspace{0.2cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm](-){$-$};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = -](1){1};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 1](2){2};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 2](.){.};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = .](3){3};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 3](4){4};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 4](5){5};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 5](6){6};
    \end{tikzpicture}\vspace{0.2cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm](-){$-$};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = -](1){1};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 1](2){2};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 2](.){.};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = .](3){3};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 3](4){4};
        \node[draw, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm, right of = 4](6){6};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the lines in `enumerate` and `tikzpicture` are not on the same level. I tried using `vspace{}` but that didn't help me. I want my document like the following image.

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 2):

You should keep your MWE as minimal. I remove those unrelated packages. For margins, your settings are not make sense for me. I recommend you using geometery package. I don't think `minipage` and `tikzpicture` are necessary here. You could type those numbers and decimal point using `\hbox to length` inside a `\fbox`. Put `\strut` before to make the each box with standard and fixed height. And define a command using `\foreach` from `tikz` package to type several boxes in a row.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\def\baselinestretch{2.0}

%\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm} 
%\setlength{\textheight}{21cm}
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.15cm}% doesn't make sense if you don't have twoside document. Your textwidth out of the paper 

% use geometry package instead
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

%define a new command to type those numbers with frame for you.
\newcommand{\printf}[1]{%
\foreach \n in {#1}
{%
\fbox{\hbox to 0.8cm{\strut\hfil\n\hfil}}%
}%
}


\begin{document}
If we want to display a real number in decimal point representation (non-scientific format), the character sequence becomes \%w.pf. The character sequence \%w.pf indicates that the associated data item should be output as a floating-point number, in non-scientific format, which occupies a field of at least w characters, and has n figures after the decimal point.
\begin{enumerate}
        \item printf(``\%f”,12. 3456);\;$\to$ \printf{1,2,.,3,4,5,6,0,0}
        \item printf(``\%7.4f”,12. 3456);\;$\to$ \printf{1,2,.,3,4,5,6}
        \item printf(``\%7.2f”,12. 3456);\;$\to$ \printf{,,1,2,.,3,4}
        \item printf(``\%-7.2f”,12. 3456);\;$\to$ \printf{1,2,.,3,4,,}
        \item printf(``\%8.4f”,-12. 3456);\;$\to$ \printf{$-$,1,2,.,3,4,5,6}
        \item printf(``\%7.4f”,-12. 3456);\;$\to$ \printf{$-$,1,2,.,3,4,5}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `tikz` is an enormous load just to get `\foreach`. I'd suggest loading `pgffor` instead. While I'd also suggest `geometry`, the OP's margins look perfectly sensible to me. What seems problematic about them?

Comment: Although I'm not sure about `\evensidemargin` in a one-sided document ....

Comment: @cfr you are right, I change it to `pgffor`. Is the texwidth= 18 cm too big for the letter size paper? op's paragraph are not even fit in the page.

Comment: It will fit but it will be rather ugly as there will be an extremely narrow margin on the right. I imagine the OP has failed to take account of the 2.54cm margin TeX leaves by default on the left. (And it will not fit on A4 at all.)

Comment: @cfr that’s true.

Answer (score 1):

With `nicematrix` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printf}{ m }
{
  \begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines, corners=SE,cell-space-limits=8pt]{*{9}{wc{1em}}}
    #1
  \end{NiceTabular}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item 
  printf(``\%f”,12. 3456);\;$\to$  \printf{ 1 & 2 & . & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
}
\item 
printf(``\%7.4f”,12. 3456);\;$\to$ \printf{ 1 & 2 & . & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6}

\item 
printf(``\%7.2f”,12. 3456);\;$\to$ \printf{&&1&2&.&3&5}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]